# JQuery Calculator not work since new CSS Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have edit an new CSS Style in my HTML File.

Since this changes my Calculator not work, but I dont know why,

Firebug show nothing Errors or Warnings.

Here is the Code (jsfiddle has shifted the design)

```
--> http://jsfiddle.net/44gU9/
```

Comment: What exactly did you mean by *not work*??

Comment: i cant press the Buttons ..

Comment: Please add the code from the fiddle to your Question, Questions and Answer shouldn't rely on code from external sites!

Comment: its to long to paste here.

Comment: @Mick you can press it, you just don't see the numbers because it's hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this is working with the only problem that the width of `input#Result`is too long for the `div#calculator`, so its value (right-aligned) is not visible.

=> make your input-field smaller

Answer (score 1):

You can press buttons, but just can't see the result since your #Result field is too long and the text is right aligned
Here, I made the result field smaller:
http://jsfiddle.net/qE62y/

```
        #Result {
            border:1px solid #AAA;
            margin:7px 5px;
            font-size:25px;
            text-align:right;
            padding:10px 7px 7px;
            background-color:#FFF;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #ccc inset;
            border-radius:2px;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-position:9px 11px;
            width:150px;
        }
```